# How to check if my parentNode is a <a> html tag - YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

I have : `<a href="mylink.html"><img src="abc.png" /></a>`.
I want to know if my `img` parentNode is a `<a>` tag or not.

I use YUI 3 library, but I can use native JS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I need it in YUI or in native...

Comment: @duffymo — YUI is a perfectly good library (frankly, I think it is rather better then jQuery, especially on the documentation front), but this task is trivial enough that a library doesn't really help matters much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grab the parent node, get its node name, then compare to the node name you want. To make sure something is a link (rather than some other kind of anchor), test to see if it has a filled in href property.

```
node.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a' && node.parentNode.href !== "";
```

Comment: The `typeof` check you are doing always evaluates to true

Comment: @Esailija — So it does, serves me right for trying to be clever without testing it. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using YUI, then `imgNode.ancestor().test('a')`.